# Run oncreate every time android app is opened

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have made an android app, when I close the app (using the home button) and reopen the app, it does not call `onCreate()` again. Instead it just loads from memory.

How can I make sure every time the app is opened `onCreate()` is executed?

---

**EDIT:**
The app has to do the same thing in `onCreate()` as in `onResume()`.

When I copy the exact code to the function `onResume()` it does not work the same.

Therefore I want to close the app (and the process) completely (or do something similar) so `onCreate()` always gets called after reopening the app.

Comment: you can use `onstart` ?

Comment: android app framework invokes Activity's callback methods such as onCreate(), onResume() and others.  if you want some code to be executed every time when app's activity is brought into foreground use onResume(). Read more about these callback at https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: I suggest that you post a separate question, where you provide a [mcve] and explain, **in detail**, what "it does not work the same" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want onCreate() to be called everytime app opens up butit does not. This is because your app will still be in recents when you are opening it again.

1. When you open app when it already exists in recents, your onStart() gets called. Try adding your logic in onStart().
2. If you want only onCreate() to be called everytime, then you must remove from recents when home is pressed. For that you need to make changes in Manifest fie for the activity.Try using the below for the activity inManifets :

   android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"

   android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"

Comment: I will try number 2. Number 1 is not an option as the code in onResume does not work the way it does in onCreate (same code).

Comment: Hi @Laura, just try using "android:noHistory="true" in you manifest under that activity. This will for sure work.

Comment: In combination with clearTaskOnLaunch and finishOnTaskLaunch or not? I will try this tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: This worked for me! OnCreate is executed every time. Thank you!

Comment: It will work for any activity. Declare in Manifest for the next activity that is started for result.

Comment: I worked around this problem. Android documentation: Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. In this case, onActivityResult() is never called if you start another activity for a result from this activity.... So that is why

Answer (score 1):

> when I close the app (using the home button)

That does not "close the app", for any typical definition of "close". The closest analogy, in a desktop OS, would be minimizing the app.

> How can I make sure every time the app is opened onCreate() is executed?

You don't. Instead, you use other [lifecycle methods](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) that are more appropriate, such as `onStart()`, which will be called both after `onCreate()` (when the activity is first created) *and* when the activity is returning to the foreground from having been in the background.

Comment: I know it does not close the app. If there is a proper way to close the app (and maybe it's process) so reopening the app will call onCreate I would like to know about it. 
I know I can override onstart, but the thing is: the app does not act the same when reopening the app as it does when starting the app.

Comment: @Laura: "If there is a proper way to close the app (and maybe it's process) so reopening the app will call onCreate I would like to know about it" -- that is not an appropriate solution, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I have put `System.exit(1)` in the `onStop()` function. After opening the app from recent apps, it runs `onCreate()`.

So this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just do call `onResume` this will do the trick.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // TODO: do what ever you want 
}
```

Have a look at this site: [Activity-lifecycle concepts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc)

[image]

Comment: I know this is a way, but the app does something well on startup (onCreate) while on reopening (onResume) it has to do the same thing, but it does not. So I would like to have it call onCreate every time the app opens (either start or reopen)